# Excel - Table Issue

Tags: excel, dynamic, size, pivot

I've got a number of table on different worksheets that have items sorted into categories which can be found on yet another worksheet.

I've then created pivot tables of these tables, and would like to combine them, which is where my problem is. To combine them all of the categories must be listed, but sometimes there aren't any items of certain categories, meaning that it causes problems.

I had solved this by filling the bottom of the tables with the same data from the lookup manually, though I find myself now wanting to increase the number of categories, and without manually changing all of the tables (which is awkward and annoying) I've not been able to keep all of the tables having at least one entry of each category.

I'm open to flexible solutions here, so if you think you have a weird way around it then let me know. I'd prefer not to use macros but if there are no other ways then I realise I may have to.

Here is a link to an example which should help to explain what I'm trying to do.
http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

Comment: Can you sketch out what you have and want to achieve? Maybe it's too late for me but I don't have a clear vision of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to attach an example spreadsheet when I posted the question but I completely forgot. Will attach now.